# Is missing later flight in connecting flight possible?

Tags: india, short-connections, domestic-travel, connecting-flights

Has anyone traveled with connecting flights and skipped the other flight will there be any issues.

for instance: my ticket is from: Bangalore -> Mumbai -> Delhi (no return ticket)
and what if I skip the Mumbai -> Delhi flight, will there be any issues in my future travel ??

PS.: I will only be taking hand baggage so no issue for baggage being directly sent to final destination.

Comment: Unless you do this regularly, the airline is unlikely to seek remuneration.  This is called Hidden City Ticketing and not at all uncommon.

Comment: If it is a round-trip ticket, very often the return leg will be void if you intentionally do not board a leg of your outward journey.

Answer (score 1):

Most airlines will just flag you as no show, same as if you missed the flight for some reason.

What happens is that if you do this often, they may start flagging your future reservations. That is a common worry of people doing *Hidden City Ticketing* but once or even a few times is unlikely to get you into trouble.